# Can someone explain AWS GET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For reference: [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html)

When I do a get request on the root bucket it comes back with `test/` and `test/subdir/` both 0 bytes. Which is correct, there should be 2 folders up there. When I upload a file to `test/subdir/file`. The root bucket has an item with the `key=test/subdir/file`. `test/` and `test/subdir/` are still 0 bytes. When I do a get request on `test/subdir/` it returns nothing.

What's going on here?

Note: I do not have access to the console.

Comment: show us each GET command you used, and paste the result here.

Comment: I'm using s3curl.pl that Amazon supplies. And here are the results of the root directory.

Comment: Got it, [s3-curl.zip](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/s3-curl.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greg, this might sound confusing at first, but the truth is that there's no such thing as "a folder" in Amazon S3. I'll explain.

The data structure of S3 is like a flat list of objects -- not like a tree. When you think you have a "file" called `puppy.jpg` inside a "folder" called `pics`, what you actually have is **an object** which key is `pics/puppy.jpg`. Note that the `/` character is not any more special than the `.` character, or the `p` characters.

You might be thinking, *Bruno is nuts, I see folders in the AWS Management Console*. True, you see the folders. But they are actually *emulated* by the GUI.

When you create a folder through the AWS Management Console, what it will actually do is create **an object** which name is the full path of the "folder", with a trailing slash, and 0 bytes. Just like the `test/` object (not "folder") and the `test/subdir/` object (not "folder") you mention in your question.

To actually identify and draw "folders", the AWS Management Console (as well as many other S3 browsing tools) is doing is some API magic with the parameters `delimiter` and `prefix`.

Now, knowing the fact that there's no such thing as a folder, and that they are *emulated* through the use of those 0-byte, trailing-/ objects, it should be easy to understand why you see the `test/` object as a 0-byte object... The same reasoning would explain why you see *nothing* when you do a GET on a "folder" -- you are actually downloading a 0-byte object!

Finally, as a conclusion, there's no easy way to obtain from S3 the size of "a folder" (they don't exist...). The only way would be for you to list all the objects with that *prefix* and add their sizes. Or keep an index of your object ("files" and "folders") in some kind of database with more advanced querying capabilities.